# Django Error : No property found matching the query

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

So I am building a site with Django where a `Property` has an `agent` who lists it, in the `AgentDetailView` I am rendering all the agent's information but I also want to render the agent's listed properties in the same page. So I was trying the `Property.objects.filter` method but to no success.

How can I make my code work? Thanks in advance!

My models.py:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    price = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 10000)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    description =  models.TextField()
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'Images/')
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'Images/')
    image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'Images/')
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agent_description = models.TextField()
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    bedrooms = models.IntegerField()
    bathrooms = models.IntegerField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='')

class Agent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'Images/')
    bio = models.TextField()
    instagram = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    twitter = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    facebook = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='')
```

My views.py:

```
class AgentDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Agent
    template_name = 'blog/agent_detail.html'
    slug_field = 'slug'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Property.objects.filter(agent=self.kwargs.get('agent'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get agent by slug in the AgentDetailView, you should change the query to:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Property.objects.filter(agent__slug=self.kwargs.get('agent'))
```